# How to retrieve latitude and longitude point from Multipolygon in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Has anyone used PHP to parse the Polygon/Multipolygon geometry data held in MySql?
I am new to the spatial function in MySQL. Please help me take the latitude and longitude point from a multipolygon in MySQL.

I have a table which has a geometry column of type `MULTIPOLYGON` and I wish to list all of the discreet points in the polygon(s).

First, I obtain the Nth polygon of interest as text:

```
SELECT AsText( GeometryN( polygon_geom, 1)) FROM spatial_search_geometry
```

This gives me a string in this form:

> POLYGON((280593.054673555 254679.164020664,280554.160845461
>   254662.495237195,280515.267017367 254645.826453727,280531.935800836 254573.595058695,280562.495237195 254448.57918268,280593.054673555 254270.77882568,280556.938976039 254065.197162898,280518.045147945 253745.712146414,280476.373189273 253759.602799305,280429.144969445 253779.049713352,280423.588708289 253876.284283586,280398.585533086 253917.956242258,280454.148144648 253981.853245555,280512.488886789 254101.312860414,280518.045147945 254231.884997586,280495.82010332 254368.013395914,280468.038797539 254423.576007477,280495.82010332 254454.135443836,280501.376364477 254490.251141352,280429.144969445 254604.154495055,280493.041972742 254643.048323148,280479.151319852 254690.276542977,280495.82010332 254795.845504945,280473.595058695 254848.62998593,280493.041972742 254948.642686742,280462.482536383 254998.649037148,280448.591883492 255087.549215648,280484.707581008 255223.677613977,280556.938976039 255426.48114618,280593.054673555 255423.703015602,280645.839154539 255420.924885023,280709.736157836 255429.259276758,280729.183071883 255387.587318086,280729.183071883 255323.690314789,280706.958027258 255276.462094961,280684.732982633 255254.237050336,280651.395415695 255232.012005711,280656.951676852 255195.896308195,280665.286068586 255126.443043742,280665.286068586 255076.436693336,280665.286068586 255029.208473508,280620.835979336 254951.42081732,280584.72028182 254934.752033852,280531.935800836 254940.308295008,280593.054673555 254679.164020664))

From this output how do I get each latitude and longitude point?

Comment: are you using [geophp](https://geophp.net/)?

Comment: I am using d3.js on laravel . I want to locate  the lat long position on map.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to parse an array, how about this?

Assuming that the first number is Longitude then Latitude and each pair of numbers are the appropriate coordinates.

```
$i=0;
foreach(POLYGON[]){
echo="Longitude: ".POLYGON[$i];
echo="Latitude: ".POLYGON[$i+1];
$i= $i+2;
}
```